# Auto focus Text field After Ajax refresh

Tags: ajax

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("BulkEditID_Lok").value = "";
document.getElementById("BulkEditID_Lok").focus();

</script>
```

I want to somewhat auto focus to my text field after my page refresh using AJAX, it will focus on my field for like a mile seconds. But it will be grid out / out of focus after wards.

Please advise